# Getting schema validation error when a key is sometimes not present in JSON response in v1.1.0. The same code works in v0.9.6

Tags: json, karate

Here is the sample Scenario. I have used the ## to make sure the code passes even if the "store" key is not present in the json, but still it fails for key not present.

Scenario: Do Schema Validations

```
* def response =
   """
    {
   "depts": [
    {
      "id": 192,
      "store": {
        "code": "1004",
        "usable": true
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 201,
      "store": {
        "code": "983",
        "usable": false
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 203
    }
  ]
  } 
  """

* json response_json = response

* def store_schema = {"code":'#string',"usable":'#boolean'}

* def depts_schema = {"id":'#number',"store":'##(store_schema)'}

* match response ==
  """
  {
    "depts": '##[] depts_schema'
  }
  """
```

**Output for v1.1.0**

```
  $.depts[2] | not equal | **actual does not contain key - 'store'** (MAP:MAP)
  {"id":203}
  {"id":"#number","store":{"code":"#string","usable":"#boolean"}}
```

**The same code works in v0.9.6**

Has something changed in 1.0 or am I missing an important aspect of the upgrade guide?

Comment: Can someone please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

including round brackets for the dept_schema resolved the issue

Again, it was already mentioned in the 1.0 Upgrade guide which i missed

- def depts_schema = ({"id":'#number',"store":'##(store_schema)'})